# Button Press Not Recognized (VBA UI Automation Library)

Tags: vba, user-interface, automation, ui-automation

Not all VBA users are aware that there is a library for UI automation which can be referenced. Please see this link: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/)

I have been in the process of automating the UI of a specific program but have encountered a slight error.

I am able to set all automation elements of the application successfully. These elements all happen to be buttons. However, when invoking the pattern which is meant to "click" the button, not every "click" is successful. In fact, if i call the invoke method three times per button, most of the "clicks" go through.

How can I be sure that each "click" is successful with only one method use per button? Per request, I have included sample code below:

```
Private Sub keypadPress(key As Byte)
    Dim keypadButtonPress As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Dim keypadButton As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement
    Dim pCondition As UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationCondition
    Dim patternID As Long
    Set pCondition = propertyCondition(cAuto, "Button" & key, xAutomation)
    Set keypadButton = keypad.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, pCondition)
    patternID = UIAutomationClient.UIA_InvokePatternId
    Set keypadButtonPress = keypadButton.GetCurrentPattern(patternID)
    Debug.Print patternID
    keypadButtonPress.Invoke
End Sub
```

The key parameter simply is used to alternate the name of the button being pressed.

To expand on what unsuccessful means, the code executes, yet the buttons do not seem to be pressed. Nothing happens on the client side. When I invoke a button three times, it generally works, but sometimes it includes extra presses. For this reason, I cannot rely on three calls of the invoke method per button.

Comment: can you add a code snippet on how you've implemented the methods? What does "not successful" mean?  The wrong code executes, no code executes, you get an error, etc.

Comment: Maybe a timing problem?

Comment: @sous2817 Not successful meaning the code executes, yet the button does not seem to be pressed. Nothing happens on client side. When I invoke the button three times, it generally works but sometimes includes extra presses.

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks, I actually have tried messing with timing and focus, but it does not seem to matter. The timing options I have tested I think were to utilize the `application.wait Now + timeValue("00:00:01")` between presses.

Comment: I have used AHK (AutoHotKey) for that some years ago and I remember that timing was a tricky thing. Ended up with setting a lot of waits to ensure that everything is working.

Comment: Same problem in C++ application in Windows 10. I am checking all return codes which are OK. Nevertheless sometimes click is ignored. Sometimes the button gets focus but is not clicked. The probability of problem is higher if I try to work with computer during automation process or if automating more than one instance of application.